# Notifications mechanism for Windows using .Net

Tags: .net, windows, notifications, messaging

I am looking for the different notification mechanisms available for Windows that will allow a user to subscribe to notifications and a server (running on a different machine) send a message to the user over the network. (The message should then be shown to the user via a Toast notification on their desktop).

I thought of Growl for Windows. But I am not sure if it can be used over a network (if it can, what needs to be run on the server)?

Other ideas:

- custom plugin for Office Communicator - that sends messages to all people in a group,
- a custom written client app that displays the toasts as well as a custom written server app that sends messages to all subscribers.

Are there any other Microsoft technologies that I could use for this purpose? (Ideally it should allow me to develop the customizations in a .Net language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Growl for Windows does work over the network. Actually, there are three ways to configure it:

1. if you run GfW on the server, you can set up the server to forward any notifications it receives to other computers. most of the configuration is centralized on the originating machine (server), or
2. you can subscribe client machines to listen for notifications from the server. if allowed by the server (which must also be running GfW), then most of the configuration can be done on each client
3. use the growlnotify command line tool to send out the notifications. you can simply specify the computer name/address and the notification will be sent over the network.

a very brief (user-focused) overview of forwarding and subscriptions can be found here: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/#network

detailed info about growlnotify can be found here: http://www.growlforwindows.com/gfw/help/growlnotify.aspx

if you want more info from a developer's perspective, post a question in the GfW discussion group: http://groups.google.com/group/growl-for-windows?hl=en